# AmCharts serial multiple data sets

Tags: amcharts

Taking a look at different examples on the documentation, I found that the only way to include multiple graphs (or lines) on a serial chart would be to do so by placing the data in one array as such:

```
[{
  category: 1,
  value1: .8,
  value2: .64,
},
{
  category: 2,
  value1: .75,
  value2: -.4,    
}];
```

However, this is rather tedious if you have multiple data sets you are trying to display at once; is there an alternative way to do this, where you would pass multiple arrays at once (this is what I figured an implementation would look like, but it is not the case):

```
[ 
// First set of data
{ category: 0, value: .5},
{ category: 1, value: .5},
{ category: 2, value: .5},
{ category: 3, value: .5},
{ category: 4, value: .3},
{ category: 5, value: 1}
],
// Second set of data
[
{ category: 0, value: .5 },
{ category: 1, value: .3 },
{ category: 2, value: .25 },
{ category: 3, value: .6 },
{ category: 4, value: .79 },
{ category: 5, value: .81 }
]],
```

Any ideas on how this may be done? Or would I need to do switch to a different type of chart?

Comment: Try the chart editor https://live.amcharts.com/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in the regular AmCharts JavaScript Charts library. The only supported format is a single array of objects with the values consolidated by category as you've noticed. You'll have to preprocess your data beforehand.

The AmCharts Stock Chart library supports separate arrays of data in the dataSets array, however it only supports date-based data.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "dataSets": [{
     // other properties omitted
     "dataProvider": [{
        category: "2017-08-01,
        value: 3
      }, {
        category: "2017-08-02,
        value: 2
      }, {
        category: "2017-08-03,
        value: 1
      }, // ...
     ]
  }, {
     // other properties omitted
     "dataProvider": [{
        category: "2017-08-01,
        value: 10
      }, {
        category: "2017-08-02,
        value: 9
      }, {
        category: "2017-08-03,
        value: 5
      }, // ...
     ]
  },
  // ...
  ]
  // ...
});
```

You can see this in action in the any of the [stock chart demos](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/#stock-chart).